# Usefulness/point of function "symbol-name"?

Tags: common-lisp

On first look it seems somewhat silly to have a function which returns the name of a symbol, which must be called using the name of that same symbol. i.e. it should already be obvious in the calling context what the function will return. On the other hand there is `identity` which is sometimes useful (I forget where just now) but I supposed (perhaps wrongly) that `symbol-function` is there for a reason other than simply to act as a kind of identity.

However, the [hyperspec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_2.htm) offers a possible hint:

```lisp
 (symbol-name 'temp) =>  "TEMP" 
 (symbol-name :start) =>  "START"
 (symbol-name (gensym)) =>  "G1234" ;for example
```

I note that `:start` means get the name of the symbol `start` from the keyword package, where the keyword package is denoted simply by `:`. 
(`:keyword` being its longer form, unnecessary to use). Thus, in this case `symbol-name` plays the role of simply removing the package prefix.

The other thing it might do is, given an implementation is case insensitive, it would get the actual name by removing case in the symbol name supplied.

Is that roughly it or is there any importance to this function I am missing?

One thing I was confused by about symbols (cleared up now) is that `symbol-plist` does not tell you everything about the symbol (say, whether it holds the value of a special variable or function). Rather, plist is a mainly legacy feature now largely replaced by hashtables. So, a call to `symbol-plist` is going to return `NIL` even if one has set a special variable on the symbol.

One final question on that, Paul Graham says in Chapter 8 (p133), that "You can use symbols as data objects and as names for things without understanding how the two are related". Would it be correct say that if we rarely now use plists, that, today, we generally don't use symbols "as data objects" at all, instead, ***just as names for things*** (allbeit with the duality in CL of course, i.e. `symbol-function` and `symbol-value` simultaneously).

Comment: symbol plists are equivalent to *weak* hash-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you want to write some protocol for transmitting bits of structure between two different systems over some serial channel

```
(defgeneric transmit-object (o stream))
```

What is the method for symbols going to look like?

```
(defmethod transmit-object ((o symbol) stream)
  ... (symbol-name o) ...)
```

In particular you certainly do not know the name of the symbol at the point where you need to reason about it, and you could not write such a protocol without using `symbol-name` (or some absolutely appalling hack like printing the symbol to a string and using that).

Regarding `symbol-plist`, the implementation is completely at liberty to keep all sorts of information on the property list of a symbol.  I am not even sure that the implementation is not allowed to do (a cleverer version of):

```
(defun symbol-value (s)
  (let* ((d (load-time-value (cons nil nil)))
         (v (get s secret-value-indicator d)))
    (when (eq v d)
      (error ...))
    v))
```

It may be that this is not allowed, but I am not sure.  Certainly it was once fairly common for function definitions to be kept in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Symbols are objects.  You can create them and pass them around programmatically.  One of the properties of these objects is their name, which is a string.  `Symbol-name` is the reader (not accessor) for that.  That's all.

Symbols are *also* used in the representation of code.  In this case, they are created by the reader and used by the compiler.  This is not their only use, however, and the spec makes no such assumptions either.  I hope that this addresses the core of your question.

Here is a function that, given a symbol, returns a symbol interned in the same package but with a reversed name:

```
(defun reverse-symbol (symbol)
  (intern (make-symbol (reverse (symbol-name symbol)))
          (symbol-package symbol)))
```

Here is a function that, given a string designator, returns the designated string:

```
(defun designated-string (string-designator)
  (ctypecase string-designator
    (string string-designator)
    (symbol (symbol-name string-designator))))
```

You can also do all kinds of shenanigans in macros and compiler macros by inspecting the names of the symbols in the given form and applying some conventions (not that you *should*…).

Answer (score 1):

It's not so silly when you process symbol names. When you for example build preprocessor - you read some data, convert it to list structures and then some code is processing those list and trigger some additional logic when `symbol-name` is lets say `defun-my-ubermacro`. It's exactly what's in Graham quote - you treat symbols as data.

And (in my opinion) it's not correct to say, that when you don't use plists, you generally don't use symbols as data. Plists are only on of many places where it's useful feature. A lot of what macros do is processing symbols as data / names.

Answer (score 1):

> On first look it seems somewhat silly to have a function which returns the name of a symbol, which must be called using the name of that same symbol.

That's wrong. `symbol-name` is called with a symbol and not a name. It returns the name as a string.

> I note that :start means get the name of the symbol start from the keyword package, where the keyword package is denoted simply by :. (:keyword being its longer form, unnecessary to use). Thus, in this case symbol-name plays the role of simply removing the package prefix.

No, `symbol-name` returns the name of the symbol as a string. The keyword symbol is an object of type `symbol`.

A symbol is a data type and has several *cells*:

- the name, a string
- possibly a function
- possibly a value
- a property list
- optionally the home package it is interned in

> don't use symbols "as data objects" at all, instead, just as names for things

No, symbols as data objects have many purposes. For example Lisp source code uses many symbols. But it can also appear in all sorts of data.

```
CL-USER 6 > 'foo
FOO

CL-USER 7 > (type-of 'foo)
SYMBOL

CL-USER 8 > (symbol-name 'foo)
"FOO"

CL-USER 9 > (type-of (symbol-name 'foo))
SIMPLE-BASE-STRING

CL-USER 10 > (mapcar #'symbol-name '(a b c defun foo bar))
("A" "B" "C" "DEFUN" "FOO" "BAR")

CL-USER 11 > (mapcar #'type-of *)
(SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING SIMPLE-BASE-STRING)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't accepted an answer, here is my take.

For most day-to-day programming symbols, and therefore SYMBOL-NAME,
aren't very useful. Mostly they are used for their
unique-ness. However they shine when you are modifying the compiler
with macros.

Here are 3 examples where SYMBOL-NAME is used:

Firstly, LOOP is the CL generic looping construct, it works via
placeholder symbols in a way that some claim is un-lispy, but it
remains very handy, especially if you are stepping things in parallel.

The following 3 forms are equivalent (at run-time):

```
(loop for i in list collect i)
(loop :for i :in list :collect i)
(loop #:for i #:in list #:collect i)
```

I, personally, prefer the third form because it makes it really
obvious where the LOOP magic is happening, and also avoids interning
symbols in any package (which is usually harmless, but not
always). That the third works at all *requires* the existence of
SYMBOL-NAME

Secondly, I don't make much use of CLOS but classes are undeniably
useful. DEFCLASS tends to be too verbose for what I want to do though,
so I often employ a macro that uses implied symbols. So:

```
(defbean peer ()
  (id)
  (next
   beats))
```

Becomes:

```
(defclass peer nil
  ((id :initarg :id :reader peer-id)
   (next :initarg :next :accessor peer-next)
   (beats :initarg :beats :accessor peer-beats)))
```

Saving much typing. Notice how the slot name is converted to a keyword
for the initargs, and how reader and accessor names are created.

Some don't like this sort of macro, and I can see how it might be
problematic if you have a large team with everyone doing this all over
the shop (though `M-.` and `C-c ret` are always available), but for
small teams I think this is one of the best reasons to use lisp,
customising it to how you actually want to use it.

Thirdly, my sqlite helper library uses SYMBOL-NAME to generate SQL
statements (along with some more implied symbols) for even more
code-saving:

```
(defsqlite-table artists
  (id :auto-key)
  (artist-name :t)
  (sort-artist-name :t :n))
```

Becomes something pretty huge:

```
(progn
 (defparameter +create-artists-sql+
   "CREATE TABLE artists (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   artist_name TEXT NOT NULL,
   sort_artist_name TEXT
)")
 (defun create-artists-table (pjs-sqlite::db pjs-sqlite::recursive log)
   ###)
 (eval-when (:load-toplevel)
   ###)
 (defun insert-artists
        (pjs-sqlite::db artist-name sort-artist-name &key (id nil id-p))
   ###)
 (defun update-artists
        (pjs-sqlite::db id
         &key (artist-name nil artist-name-p)
         (sort-artist-name nil sort-artist-name-p))
   ###)
 (defun delete-artists (pjs-sqlite::db id)
   (with-sqlite-statements (pjs-sqlite::db
                            (pjs-sqlite::stmt
                             "DELETE FROM artists WHERE id = ?"))
     ###)))
```

(I stripped out a lot of code that would be distracting, but it should
be clear how I mapped symbols to sql identifiers)

I hope this gives you some ideas on what sort of things SYMBOL-NAME
can be used for.